# Download a file from the internet in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, filepath

- I am having a problem naming the file I have downloaded and assigning it a file type. (see on line 4 of the code).
- Saving the file in any location, I specifically assign to it. not in the same directory as the program. e.g in Downloads, documents, or any directory.

```
import requests
downloadUrl = input('Enter URL: ')
file_url = requests.get(downloadUrl)
dir_path = input("Enter path and name of the file: ")
f = open(dir_path,'a+')
```

Any inputs?

Comment: This looks quite similar to [this other recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67003746/2745495).

Comment: @GinoMempin yeah! but it is not answered, so I still need an answer sir, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a requests object not a file path

```
file_url = requests.get(downloadUrl)
with open(file_url, 'w+') as f:
```

You would need to open a filepath on disk somewhere and write to that

See Using the request Module on https://stackabuse.com/download-files-with-python/

EDIT: From comments on post

```
In [584]: link = "https://www.annualreports.com/HostedData/AnnualReportArchive/3/NASDAQ_QFIN_2018.pdf"

In [585]: import requests

In [586]: file_url = requests.get(link)

In [587]: with  open('/tmp/NASDAQ_QFIN_2018.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    ...:     f.write(file_url.content)
    ...:

In [588]: ls -al /tmp/NASDAQ_QFIN_2018.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 ME  wheel  1796199  9 Apr 15:21 /tmp/NASDAQ_QFIN_2018.pdf
```

Comment: i think you mean `with open(filepath, 'w+') as f:` as `file_url`  contains response and not the url of the file you want to create.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, but I'm getting a **PermissionError: [Errno 13] Error** after adding with open(filepath, 'w+') as f:

Comment: That is because you are trying to open a Directory not a file you would need to download to `C:\Users\PacY\Downloads\myfilename.whatever`

Comment: Okay. I have done it. Now I can enter a path as `userinput` refer to edited codes above. the script will download the file in the specified path, but the problem the downloaded file will be empty. `0KB`

Comment: What is an example URL you are trying to download?

Comment: [link] (https://www.annualreports.com/HostedData/AnnualReportArchive/3/NASDAQ_QFIN_2018.pdf) its a `pdf`

Comment: See update to my post.  I dont have a Windows machine but cant see why it would be different